2sxc ImageFlowModule - FATAL Exceptions
We have a site that's been running into a plethora of issues with the 2sxc module.
I am currently getting a lot of "Remote Host Closed the connection" stemming from the ToSic.Imageflow.Dnn.ImageflowModule.NotModified(HttpContext context) call.  And looking at todays logs - I'm seeing a lot for other Imageflow type calls.
We are running 2sxc 16.7 version
DNN is 9.13.02
Here's a snippet of our log for today - all of these were logged at the same time:
2024-04-29 05:23:40.528-05:00 [dnn3web][D:2][T:82][FATAL] DotNetNuke.Web.Common.Internal.DotNetNukeHttpApplication - System.Web.HttpException (0x80070057): The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x80070057.
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32 result, Boolean throwOnDisconnect)
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ExplicitFlush()
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush, Boolean async)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush()
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
   at ToSic.Imageflow.Dnn.ImageflowModule.<ProcessWithStreamCache>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at ToSic.Imageflow.Dnn.ImageflowModule.<ImageflowRequestAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.TaskAsyncHelper.EndTask(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)
2024-04-29 05:23:40.529-05:00 [dnn3web][D:2][T:86][FATAL] DotNetNuke.Web.Common.Internal.DotNetNukeHttpApplication - System.Web.HttpException (0x80070057): The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x80070057.
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32 result, Boolean throwOnDisconnect)
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ExplicitFlush()
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush, Boolean async)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush()
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
   at ToSic.Imageflow.Dnn.ImageflowModule.<ProcessWithStreamCache>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at ToSic.Imageflow.Dnn.ImageflowModule.<ImageflowRequestAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.TaskAsyncHelper.EndTask(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)
2024-04-29 05:23:40.529-05:00 [dnn3web][D:2][T:52][FATAL] DotNetNuke.Web.Common.Internal.DotNetNukeHttpApplication - System.Web.HttpException (0x80070057): The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x80070057.
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32 result, Boolean throwOnDisconnect)
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ExplicitFlush()
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush, Boolean async)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush()
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
   at ToSic.Imageflow.Dnn.ImageflowModule.<ProcessWithStreamCache>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at ToSic.Imageflow.Dnn.ImageflowModule.<ImageflowRequestAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.TaskAsyncHelper.EndTask(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)
2024-04-29 05:23:40.529-05:00 [dnn3web][D:2][T:134][FATAL] DotNetNuke.Web.Common.Internal.DotNetNukeHttpApplication - System.Web.HttpException (0x80070057): The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x80070057.
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32 result, Boolean throwOnDisconnect)
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ExplicitFlush()
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush, Boolean async)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush()
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
   at ToSic.Imageflow.Dnn.ImageflowModule.<ProcessWithStreamCache>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at ToSic.Imageflow.Dnn.ImageflowModule.<ImageflowRequestAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.TaskAsyncHelper.EndTask(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)
2024-04-29 05:23:40.530-05:00 [dnn3web][D:2][T:9][FATAL] DotNetNuke.Web.Common.Internal.DotNetNukeHttpApplication - System.Web.HttpException (0x80070057): The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x80070057.
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32 result, Boolean throwOnDisconnect)
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ExplicitFlush()
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush, Boolean async)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush()
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
   at ToSic.Imageflow.Dnn.ImageflowModule.<ProcessWithStreamCache>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at ToSic.Imageflow.Dnn.ImageflowModule.<ImageflowRequestAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.TaskAsyncHelper.EndTask(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)
2024-04-29 05:23:40.530-05:00 [dnn3web][D:2][T:77][FATAL] DotNetNuke.Web.Common.Internal.DotNetNukeHttpApplication - System.Web.HttpException (0x80070057): The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x80070057.
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32 result, Boolean throwOnDisconnect)
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ExplicitFlush()
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush, Boolean async)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush()
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
   at ToSic.Imageflow.Dnn.ImageflowModule.<ProcessWithStreamCache>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at ToSic.Imageflow.Dnn.ImageflowModule.<ImageflowRequestAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.TaskAsyncHelper.EndTask(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)
2024-04-29 05:23:40.535-05:00 [dnn3web][D:2][T:90][FATAL] DotNetNuke.Web.Common.Internal.DotNetNukeHttpApplication - System.Web.HttpException (0x80070057): The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x80070057.
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32 result, Boolean throwOnDisconnect)
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ExplicitFlush()
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush, Boolean async)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush()
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
   at ToSic.Imageflow.Dnn.ImageflowModule.<ProcessWithStreamCache>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at ToSic.Imageflow.Dnn.ImageflowModule.<ImageflowRequestAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.TaskAsyncHelper.EndTask(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)

Any thoughts suggestions would be so helpful.

I haven't noticed anything similar so far.
By the wording I assume the browser or crawler disconnected, before receiving the data it requested. Similar posts SO seem to indicate this, eg. Accepted way to prevent "The remote host closed the connection" exception
Could you try to verify?
I guess if it is verified, we could look into not-logging-an-error in such scenarios.

Thank you for the feedback - we've been checking and monitoring a LOT of things.  I wouldn't ask you to not log the errors.  And I can't validate/prove it's an ImageFlow issue, and I know you've been overly diligent in the releases of 2sxc - so we're still monitoring.
The site in question is leaning heavily on 2SXC, is multi-portal, and is using very high CPU/RAM consistently (5x all other sites) - causing timeouts and recycles.
Currently looking into if changing the fncMode='Default' helps as well as tweaks to our code utilizing Razor in 2sxc.

So ATM there's not much to go on. If you like, you may try paid support on 2sxc.org where our experts would look at it together w/you.
